# Sql 2005 Server 32 bit SPK3 CU3 on Windows 2008 64bit OS

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2005

What type of issues can I expect if I run Sql 2005 Server 32 bit SPK3 CU3 on Windows 2008 64bit OS.  I'm really intrested to know if there are any known issues or tweaks with the configuration of sql32bit on a 64bit os.

Thanks 
:-)

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this for my company on installing SQL 2005 on Server 2008.
They may have had an older version SP but same principal applies you just may not need the hotfix or get the compatibility warning.

Microsoft SQL Server 2005:

Warning: SQL Server 2005 will give you issues when installing on x64 Server 2008. This can be worked around. Please follow these steps in the right order and do not proceed to install SQL Server 2005 with errors or warnings you most likely will need to uninstall and start over.

Understand that SQL server installation will post a known compatibility warning. This is fine and is not an issue.

The first thing that is required is to enable IIS to run 32bit applications. Specifically ASP.NET. This is accomplished with 2 adjustments in IIS Server Manager. You must globally enable 32-bit applications.

1. Open IIS Server Manager
2. Expand server in Connections Pane
3. Select Application pools
4. In Actions Pane select Set Application Pool Defaults...
5. Under General find Enable 32-Bit Applications and change from False (default value) to True
6. Next Ensure that all the installed Application Pools have 32-Bit Applications Enabled. If they do not you will receive a warning when installing SQL Server 2005.

Similarily this commmand can enable 32-Bit applications

appcmd apppool set /apppool.name:MyAppPool32bit /enable32BitAppOnWin64:true

The first thing required is to install a hotfix located in \stanley\Apps\Design and programming\SQL Server 2005\hotfix server 2008

KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950636

Once this hotfix has been applied start up the Setup.exe for SQL Server 2005. Click Continue Anyways when prompted about the known compatibility issue.

Go through the setup process to install SQL.

PS I forgot to mention the memory usage on sql 2005 x32 on a 2008 x64 server gave us alot of trouble and would use up all the ram on the server and sql would crash till it was manually reset... 
We switched to sql 2008